Problem to create User Created in AD via C# Not Visible in Exchange On-Premises Admin Center but Visible in M365
I’m encountering an issue where a user created in Active Directory (AD) using a C# script does not appear in the Exchange On-Premises Admin Center, but is visible in the Microsoft 365 (M365) dashboard. However, when I manually create a user directly in AD, it appears correctly in both the Exchange On-Premises Admin Center and the M365 dashboard.
What do you think what is happening?
